# fastest way to arrange data in python numpy based on list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have problem in arrange data in numpy
example a have list of data range :

```
numpy.array([1,3,5,4,6])
```

and I have data :

```
numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19])
```

and I need the data to be arrange to

```
numpy.array([

[1,9999,9999,9999,9999,9999,9999]

[2,3,4,9999,9999,9999]

[5,6,7,8,9,9999]

[10,11,12,13,9999,9999]

[14,15,16,17,18,19]

])
```

I thought it's a little similiar with diag / diagonal / trace functionality.

I usually done the job by using basic iteration...does numpy has this functionality so it could perform faster??

Comment: @eat: The 1st row has "1" non-9999 element, the 2nd row has "3", the 3rd row has "5", the 4th row has "4" and the last row has "6".

Comment: Apparently a mistake for 7 elems in first row?

Comment: Care to show your basic iteration code? How big arrays you are handling? Have you actually profiled where the bottleneck is? What kind of performance increases you are expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ways to arrange the data:

```
from numpy import arange, array, ones, r_, zeros
from numpy.random import randint

def gen_tst(m, n):
    a= randint(1, n, m)
    b, c= arange(a.sum()), ones((m, n), dtype= int)* 999
    return a, b, c

def basic_1(a, b, c):
    # some assumed basic iteration based
    n= 0
    for k in xrange(len(a)):
        m= a[k]
        c[k, :m], n= b[n: n+ m], n+ m

def advanced_1(a, b, c):
    # based on Svens answer
    cum_a= r_[0, a.cumsum()]
    i= arange(len(a)).repeat(a)
    j= arange(cum_a[-1])- cum_a[:-1].repeat(a)
    c[i, j]= b

def advanced_2(a, b, c):
    # other loopless version
    c[arange(c.shape[1])+ zeros((len(a), 1), dtype= int)< a[:, None]]= b
```

And some timings:

```
In []: m, n= 10, 100
In []: a, b, c= gen_tst(m, n)
In []: 1.* a.sum()/ (m* n)
Out[]: 0.531
In []: %timeit advanced_1(a, b, c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 99.2 us per loop
In []: %timeit advanced_2(a, b, c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 68 us per loop
In []: %timeit basic_1(a, b, c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.1 us per loop

In []: m, n= 50, 500
In []: a, b, c= gen_tst(m, n)
In []: 1.* a.sum()/ (m* n)
Out[]: 0.455
In []: %timeit advanced_1(a, b, c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop
In []: %timeit advanced_2(a, b, c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop
In []: %timeit basic_1(a, b, c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 227 us per loop

In []: m, n= 250, 2500
In []: a, b, c= gen_tst(m, n)
In []: 1.* a.sum()/ (m* n)
Out[]: 0.486
In []: %timeit advanced_1(a, b, c)
10 loops, best of 3: 30.4 ms per loop
In []: %timeit advanced_2(a, b, c)
10 loops, best of 3: 32.4 ms per loop
In []: %timeit basic_1(a, b, c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 2 ms per loop
```

So the basic iteration seems to be quite efficient.

**Update**:
Surely the performance of the basic iteration based implementation can still be further improved on. As a starting point suggestion; consider for example this (basic iteration based on reduced addition):

```
def basic_2(a, b, c):
    n= 0
    for k, m in enumerate(a):
        nm= n+ m
        c[k, :m], n= b[n: nm], nm
```

Comment: impressive prove, so when use numpy could faster than basic loop?? how 'big' is big size array??

Comment: @Arief Goldalworming: Just a demonstration, but basically it seems that (current) `advanced numpy` won't ever be the faster one for your case. A simple iteration seem to be always faster for 'fat' to 'square' matrices. The same can also be demonstrated for 'skinny' to 'square' matrices. (cont ...)

Comment: @Arief Goldalworming: So simply, the problem with (typical modern hardware) is that more 'advanced' solutions require also more memory, which simple iteration (and proper slicing) doesn't need. So  prefer to err on the side off doing (seemingly) more computations than using more memory. But of course don't forget to measure your actual performance with common patterns. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do this without any Python loop using advanced indexing:

```
r = numpy.array([1,3,5,4,6])
data = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19])

result = numpy.empty((len(r), r.max()), data.dtype)
result.fill(9999)
cum_r = numpy.r_[0, r.cumsum()]
i = numpy.arange(len(r)).repeat(r)
j = numpy.arange(cum_r[-1]) - cum_r[:-1].repeat(r)
result[i, j] = data
print result
```

prints

```
[[   1 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999]
 [   2    3    4 9999 9999 9999]
 [   5    6    7    8    9 9999]
 [  10   11   12   13 9999 9999]
 [  14   15   16   17   18   19]]
```

Comment: How fast would this be compared to basic iteration? Depending on the array sizes, basic iteration may still easily be more efficient. OP should post more details

Comment: @eat: It's of course impossible to answer if this is faster than the OP's code, since we don't know the OP's code.  For big arrays it will be faster than any Python loop though, and for small arrays performance shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Arief Goldalworming: With that size basic iteration may be some 4 times faster. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

And once again Sven beats us all :) My humble attempt follows,

```
from numpy import arange,array,split
from numpy import concatenate as cat
from numpy import repeat as rep

a = arange(1,20)

i = array([1,3,5,4,6])
j = max(i) - i

s = split(a,i.cumsum())
z = array([cat((t,rep(9999,k))) for t,k in zip(s[:-1],j)])

print z
```

delivers,

```
[[   1 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999]
 [   2    3    4 9999 9999 9999]
 [   5    6    7    8    9 9999]
 [  10   11   12   13 9999 9999]
 [  14   15   16   17   18   19]]
```

Comment: FWIW, your solution may be some 40 slower than solution based on basic iteration (for OP's indicated size and assumed 'average triangular shape'. Thanks

Comment: @eat: Agreed. `timeit` with 10^6 repeats gives, basic_1: 30.50s, advanced_1: 64.25s, advanced_2: 41.90s, lafrasu: 388.37s. Approximately 5-12 slower.